# No repository found under this GitHub path

Tags: android, github, repository, bintray, jcenter

I want to store an Android library on jcenter.

Before this, I created a repository on bintray. After creating the repository, I had to fill package details. In package details there was a text field `GitHub repo (user/repo)` in which I had given github link of my id `https://github.com/kishlayk`.

But after update package, it is showing `No repository found under this GitHub path`. What should I do to correct it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Github repo (user/repo)` text field should be filled with github "user/repo" (Example: `myGithubUser/myGithubRepository`).
This will import Github README file and RELEASE to Bintray under the Readme and Release Notes tabs.

You can also provide the full github url path in the VCS field located in the package details.

<sup>I am with [JFrog](http://jfrog.com), the company behind [[image]bintray](/questions/tagged/bintray) and [[image]artifactory](/questions/tagged/artifactory).</sup>

Comment: what is filled in GitHub release notes file text field?

Comment: I am using this link  https://github.com/kishlayk/litifer.github.io/releases/tag/v1.0

Comment: You'll need to fill `kishlayk/litifer.github.io`

Comment: after entering this it is showing   No release notes file found under this GitHub path

Comment: I had entered kishlayk/litifer.github.io in user/repo text field after that I have to fill GitHub release notes file text field

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got answer I will have to enter a text file name in GitHub release notes file text field which is within the repository(like https://github.com/kishlayk/litifer.github.io/blob/master/releasenotes.txt.....enter only like releasenotes.txt).If text file is not avaialble, create first.